# My chrome freezes up while loading some pages

Tags: google-chrome, freeze

Chrome version = 17.0.963.83
PC = i7 system with enough resources
My chrome is freezing up while it loads some pages.
If a youtube video is playing in chrome on a different window that sometimes freezes up while some pages load. Scrolling is also blocked and I can't click on links.
Does anybody have an idea what this might be (I don't get it on firefox)

Comment: Does it happen only when you load flash(sites like youtube) ?

Answer (score 2):

Try disabling flash pepper api, instructions [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/103292/how-to-fix-shockwave-flash-crashes-in-google-chrome/).